# How to handle contactRequest in Telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegraf.js

so am making a telegram bot using Telegraf.js in Node and the bot requires the user's phone number and in Telegraf one way of requesting phone number is like this

```
ctx.reply(
    "Phone number is required",
    {
      ...Markup.keyboard([
        Markup.button.contactRequest("Send Contact"),
      ]).resize(),
    }
  );
```

and this works perfectly fine, but I don't know how to handle the result of the contact request,
I've tried using bot.hears by treating it like a callback button **(*Markup.button.callback("Send Contact")*)**

```
bot.hears("Send Contact",(ctx)=>{
  console.log("contact received")
})
```

but this doesn't work, so I was wondering if there is a special way to handle the response of **Markup.button.contactRequest**

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. Hope it helps you too

```
await ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, "Some text", {
    parse_mode: "Markdown",
    reply_markup: {
      one_time_keyboard: true,
      keyboard: [
        [
          {
            text: "Share Phone Number",
            request_contact: true,
          },
          {
            text: "Cancel",
          },
        ],
      ],
      force_reply: true,
    },
  });
bot.on("contact", (ctx: any) => {
  const contact = ctx.message.contact.phone_number;
  console.log("Hello Contact",contact);
});
```